# Check uncompressed package size for yum update

Tags: linux, yum

When we pass the yum update command, it shows total size needed to update packages. But I think it's the compressed size.

Is there any way to check uncompressed size of packages before patching the system?

I tried to use --downloadonly option and many others but the issue is same. Total package size is 400M. However if I continue with installation step, I receive "/var needs xxx M more space" message even if there is 1.2G of available space.

Answer (score 1):

The space required is the space that the packages will take up **after** the complete installation. This is not the space required **during** installation which will be bigger. For example:

- pkg-1 is installed and takes up 100M (compressed rpm of 50M)
- pkg-2 is an update, and takes up 400M (compressed rpm of 200M)

This means that at the highest point the system will need (theoretical approximation, this also depends whether files remain the same or not, pessimistic scenario here):

- 100M for pkg-1
- 400M for pkg-2 once installed (a brief moment the files of both will be present on the system)
- 200M because probably `yum` still has the compressed pkg-2.rpm untill the installation completely finishes
- maybe some extra log files or other, but that can probably be neglected with respect to 100M.

So in this scenario I think `yum` will tell you that the update will need `300M` more space (from 100M to 400M), but at the peak moment 600M will be used.